# Trying to show equality holds between integrals with respect to a probability measure

Tags: measure-theory

> **Problem:** Let $\mu$ be a probability measure on $\left(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}\right)$, where $\mathcal{B}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$. For $t\in\mathbb{R}^+$, I want to show

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}x^2\,d\mu(x) = 2\lim_{t\to0}\frac{1-\int_{\mathbb{R}}\cos(tx)\,d\mu(x)}{t^2}.$$

---

I'm not really sure how to go about doing this.

I know by the Dominated Convergence Theorem

$$\lim_{t\to0}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\cos(tx)\,d\mu(x) = 1.$$

Therefore, distributing the limit we get an indeterminate form $(\frac{0}{0})$. So, applying L'hopital's rule and Leibniz integral rule

$$2\lim_{t\to0}\frac{1-\int_{\mathbb{R}}\cos(tx)\,d\mu(x)}{t^2} = 
2\lim_{t\to0}\frac{-\frac{d}{dt}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\cos(tx)\,d\mu(x)}{2t} = 
\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\int_{\mathbb{R}}x\sin(tx)\,d\mu(x)}{t}.$$

---

**EDIT:** If I can again apply the DCT, which I don't know if I can, then the following is what I'd do:

Similarly as before, by the Dominated Convergence Theorem

$$\lim_{t\to0}\int_{\mathbb{R}}x\sin(tx)\,d\mu(x) = 0.$$

Therefore, distributing the limit we get an indeterminate form $(\frac{0}{0})$. So, applying L'hopital's rule and Leibniz integral rule

$$\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\int_{\mathbb{R}}x\sin(tx)\,d\mu(x)}{t} = 
\lim_{t\to0}\frac{d}{dt}\int_{\mathbb{R}}x\sin(tx)\,d\mu(x) = 
\lim_{t\to0}\int_{\mathbb{R}}x^2\cos(tx)\,d\mu(x).$$

Lastly, by the Dominated Convergence Theorem again

$$\lim_{t\to0}\int_{\mathbb{R}}x^2\cos(tx)\,d\mu(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}x^2\,d\mu(x).$$

---

Though, I'm not sure where to go from here, or even if this approach is correct. Perhaps writing the $2$, in front of the limit, as integral may be helpful, i.e.

$$2 = \int_{\mathbb{R}}2\,d\mu(x).$$

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why is Leibniz integral rule applicable? I don't even see an easy justification for the stronger measure theoretic statement to exchange the derivative and the integration. Are you sure you don't know anything else about that probability measure? E.g. something like that first moments are integrable? But I guess you do. Since otherwise the l.h.s. wouldn't need to be finite. In that case the exchange is justified.

Comment: @hal4math: Well, I agree with you. It just seems to lead to a solution, given that both the Dominated Convergence Theorem and Leibniz integral rule hold.

Comment: So, assuming both x and x^2 are absolutely integrable w.r.t to $\mu$, I think your reasoning works!

Comment: @hal4math: Nice, except I'm not sure that I can assume such. The question gives the hint to write the $2$ as an integral, which differs widely from my approach...hence why I think my solution isn't correct.

Comment: I do think the l.h.s is meant to be a finite integral. From this should follow that also x is absolutely integrable. I think your approach works. Of course there also might be a different way. (I mean you get to the right result. Of course this is not an argument that you reasoning is sound. But you shouldn't give up on it that quickly. You for sure can't argue by Leibniz integral rule though.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$
2\times\frac{1-\int_{\mathbb R}\cos(tx)\,\mu(dx)}{t^2}=2\int_{\mathbb R}\frac{1-\cos(tx)}{t^2}\,\mu(dx).
$$

Suppose first that $\int_{\mathbb R}x^2\,\mu(dx)<+\infty$. Since
$$
2\times\frac{1-\cos(tx)}{t^2}\underset{t\to0}{\longrightarrow}x^2,
$$ and
$$
0\le2\times\frac{1-\cos(tx)}{t^2}\le x^2,
$$
we conclude by the dominated convergence theorem.

Suppose now that $\int_{\mathbb R}x^2\,\mu(dx)=+\infty$. Then by Fatou's lemma,
$$
+\infty=\int_{\mathbb R}x^2\,\mu(dx)=2\int_{\mathbb R}\liminf_{t\to0}\frac{1-\cos(tx)}{t^2}\,\mu(dx)\le2\liminf_{t\to0}\int_{\mathbb R}\frac{1-\cos(tx)}{t^2}\,\mu(dx),
$$
hence
$$
2\int_{\mathbb R}\frac{1-\cos(tx)}{t^2}\,\mu(dx)\underset{t\to0}{\longrightarrow}+\infty=\int_{\mathbb R}x^2\,\mu(dx).
$$